# Tag category to my multiple uploaded images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am submitting a form with multiple file upload, all I want to
   differentiate the uploaded images according to the category which they
   uploaded

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <select name="category[]" >
           <option value="13">Food</option>
           <option value="15">Medicine</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="file" multiple name="product_image[]">
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <select name="category[]" >
           <option value="13">Food</option>
           <option value="15">Medicine</option>
        </select>
     </td>
     <td>
        <input type="file" multiple name="product_image[]">
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
     </td>
  </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Selecting category as "food" and uploading one image named "food.jpg" in first row.
   Selecting category as "medicine" and uploading two images named "medicine1.jpg and medicine2.jpg" in second row and 
   On submitting my result is coming as

```
Array(
      [category] => Array
           (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => 15
           )
      [product_image] => Array
           (
            [0] => food.jpg
            [1] => medicine1.jpg
            [2] => medicine2.jpg
           )
)
```

But I want to tag image according to category value. Like I want

```
[product_image] => Array
           (
            [13] => food.jpg
            [15] => medicine1.jpg
            [15] => medicine2.jpg
           )
```

Comment: Are you saving image into db or directory?

Comment: I am saving only file name on db, image on directory.

Comment: Save into specific folder then named category wise.

Comment: No, it sholuld be dynamic, all should be through code. If existing category directory is not there then it should create new category directory according to the index of the file uploaded. but I am not able to create index according to category value.

Comment: Let us share the code for creating index

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam. I am not able to find where to start for creating index for uploaded images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95847/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-rohit-jaiswal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a hidden input field when submitting the form which contains a concatenated value of the selected category id and the filename.
The format can look like this:

> 'id_selected_category##filename'

Then you can use this delimiter (in this case ##) to retrieve the category and the filename on the server from the $_POST array and this way you know which category was selected for that image.

The name of the hidden input field in this example is:

> 'category_file'

Your `$_POST` array would then look something like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["category"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "13"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "13"
  }
  ["product_image"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "1.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "2.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "3.jpg"
  }
  ["category_file"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "13##1.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "13##2.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "13##3.jpg"
  }
}
```

For example:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['category_file'])) {
        $categoryFiles = $_POST['category_file'];

        foreach($categoryFiles as $categoryFile) {
            $categoryAndFile = array_filter(explode("##", $categoryFile));

            if (count($categoryAndFile) == 2) {
                // Here you can differentiate the uploaded images according to the category which they were uploaded
                $category = $categoryAndFile[0];
                $file = $categoryAndFile[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#theForm").submit(function() {
                var categories = $('select[name=category\\[\\]]');

                $(categories).each(function() {
                    var category = this;
                    var imageNames = $(this).parent().next().children('input[type="file"]').prop("files");

                    $(imageNames).each(function(){

                        // Concatenate the selected category with the name of the image
                        var categoryFileName = $(category).val() + '##' + this.name;

                        // Add the hidden input field
                        $('<input>').attr({
                            type: 'hidden',
                            name: 'category_file[]',
                            value: categoryFileName
                        }).appendTo("#theForm");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="theForm" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="category[]" >
                    <option value="13">Food</option>
                    <option value="15">Medicine</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" multiple name="product_image[]">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="category[]" >
                    <option value="13">Food</option>
                    <option value="15">Medicine</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" multiple name="product_image[]">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I am printing like console.log( imageNames), its showing undefined.

Comment: @rohitjaiswal What do you see when you copy all the code from the example?
Did you add the `id="theForm"` to the form?
What do you see when you do this: `var_dump($_POST);` right after `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {` and then submit?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir);  
else 

    //upload image  


    }
```

[Create directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

Create directory using above code and tutorial when you got image and just going to save into db. Then upload that image into specified directory path.

Comment: But how would I distinguish which files are to be uploaded in which directory?